# Navbar Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou iniciando na codificação web e preciso de uma ajuda em um problema, o menu que criei não está correto, ele não ficou formatado como o indicado na documentação do bootstrap, está como lista.

> ```
> Curso  
> ------------
> Início
> Perfil
> Serviços
> Depoimentos
> Contatos
> ```

Segue o código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/style.css">

    <title>Curso de bootstrap 4</title>
  </head>
  <body>

          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

              <div class="container">    
              <a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0" href="#">Curso</a>


              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">

                      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                          <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Início</a>
                          </li>
                           <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
                          </li>
                           <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços</a>
                          </li>
                           <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Depoimentos</a>
                          </li>
                           <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contatos</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>

                  </div>

            </div>
          </nav>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara seu problema é que vc está usando a estrutura do menu do Bootstrap 4, mas está indexando os arquivos CSS e JS do Bootstrap 3. Vc tem que se atentar a qual versão está usando e a qual documentação vc está usando.

Caso queira aqui está a documentação oficial da NavBar do Bootstrap 3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar

Veja aqui que é exatamente o seu código, porem com os arquivos indexados do Bootstrap 4 e funciona perfeitamente!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

                <div class="container">    
                <a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0" href="#">Curso</a>
  
  
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
  
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">
  
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Início</a>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços</a>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Depoimentos</a>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contatos</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
  
                    </div>
  
              </div>
            </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Hugocsl, irei atentar mais para cada ponto que você citou. você teria algum material para indicar?

Comment: @BrunoVirginio cara o Ricardo Sanches tem um canal no YouTube que acho que vai te ajudar bastante tem vários tutoriais de Bootstrap! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da resposta se vc achar que ajudou a resolver o problema. Assim o site não fica com a sua pergunta em aberto pendente sem resposta aceita mesmo já tendo sido resolvida. []´s